# Amazon AWS Load Balancer availability issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

My Load Balancer is having some problems. Sometimes it takes too long loading resources.  The load balancer is attached to my VPC and it contains an EC2 instance that belongs to an auto-scaling group.  It's happening roughly every 10 minutes.

Why is this happening? Is this a common problem/issue? Is there anything I can do to mitigate the issue?

Comment: Not a common problem.  Have you reviewed the ELB logs?

Answer (score 0):

High latency can be caused by several factors, such as:

- Network connectivity
- ELB configuration
- Backend web application server issues including but not limited to:

Memory utilization – One of the most common causes of web application latency is when most or all available physical memory (RAM) has been consumed on the host EC2 instance.

CPU utilization – High CPU utilization on the host EC2 instance can significantly degrade web application performance and in some cases cause a server crash.

Web server configuration – If a backend web application server exhibits high latency in the absence of excessive memory or CPU utilization, the web server configuration should be reviewed for potential problems.

Web application dependencies – If a backend web application server exhibits high latency after ruling out memory, CPU, and web server configuration issues, then web application dependencies such as external databases or Amazon S3 buckets may be causing performance bottlenecks.

Below link has some steps that you can check to trouble shoot the issue:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-latency-troubleshooting/

Comment: The application has no load. So, I think something is wrong with the ELB.